# How to find all unique paths in tree structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree

```
root1
    child1
    child2
        grandchild1
        grandchild2
    child3
root2
    child1
    child2
        grandchild1
            greatgrandchild1
```

I have an object array like tree structure like above, I want to get all unique paths in like this

```
Food->Dry Food Items->Local Dry Food Items
Food->Dry Food Items->Thai Dry Food Items
Food->Dry Food Items->Others
Food->Fruits
------
------
```

This is my object

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Food",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Dry Food Items",
                "parent_id": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "name": "Local Dry Food Items",
                        "parent_id": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "Thai Dry Food Items",
                        "parent_id": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 60,
                        "name": "Others",
                        "parent_id": 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Fruits",
                "parent_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "LG Branded",
                "parent_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Meat",
                "parent_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Sea food",
                "parent_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Vegetables",
                "parent_id": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "Local Vegetables",
                        "parent_id": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "name": "Thai Vegetables",
                        "parent_id": 10
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 38,
                "name": "Frozen",
                "parent_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 39,
                "name": "IP Kitchen",
                "parent_id": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 40,
                        "name": "IP Meat",
                        "parent_id": 39
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 41,
                        "name": "IP Starter",
                        "parent_id": 39
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 42,
                        "name": "IP Ingredients",
                        "parent_id": 39
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 43,
                        "name": "IP Sauce",
                        "parent_id": 39
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 44,
                        "name": "IP Seafood",
                        "parent_id": 39
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 45,
                        "name": "IP Starter",
                        "parent_id": 39
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 46,
                        "name": "IP Desert",
                        "parent_id": 39
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Beverage",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Bar",
                "parent_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Coffee & Tea",
                "parent_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 18,
                "name": "In Can",
                "parent_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "name": "Water",
                "parent_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 47,
                "name": "IP Bar",
                "parent_id": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Disposable",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 21,
                "name": "Disposable",
                "parent_id": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "SOE",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "name": "Cleaning Materials",
                "parent_id": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "name": "Chinaware",
                "parent_id": 4
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I get to all the nodes in the tree

```
function traverse(categories) {

        categories.forEach(function (category) {

            if (category.children && category.children.length) {
                traverse(category.children);
            }
            else {

            }

        }, this);
    }
```

Comment: tried anything?

Comment: What do you want to know ? Is it Programming problem that you have tried ?

Comment: Post a valid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion and create a function using `forEach` loop.

```js
var arr = [{"id":1,"name":"Food","parent_id":0,"children":[{"id":5,"name":"Dry Food Items","parent_id":1,"children":[{"id":11,"name":"Local Dry Food Items","parent_id":5},{"id":12,"name":"Thai Dry Food Items","parent_id":5},{"id":60,"name":"Others","parent_id":5}]},{"id":6,"name":"Fruits","parent_id":1},{"id":7,"name":"LG Branded","parent_id":1},{"id":8,"name":"Meat","parent_id":1},{"id":9,"name":"Sea food","parent_id":1},{"id":10,"name":"Vegetables","parent_id":1,"children":[{"id":14,"name":"Local Vegetables","parent_id":10},{"id":15,"name":"Thai Vegetables","parent_id":10}]},{"id":38,"name":"Frozen","parent_id":1},{"id":39,"name":"IP Kitchen","parent_id":1,"children":[{"id":40,"name":"IP Meat","parent_id":39},{"id":41,"name":"IP Starter","parent_id":39},{"id":42,"name":"IP Ingredients","parent_id":39},{"id":43,"name":"IP Sauce","parent_id":39},{"id":44,"name":"IP Seafood","parent_id":39},{"id":45,"name":"IP Starter","parent_id":39},{"id":46,"name":"IP Desert","parent_id":39}]}]},{"id":2,"name":"Beverage","parent_id":0,"children":[{"id":16,"name":"Bar","parent_id":2},{"id":17,"name":"Coffee & Tea","parent_id":2},{"id":18,"name":"In Can","parent_id":2},{"id":19,"name":"Water","parent_id":2},{"id":47,"name":"IP Bar","parent_id":2}]},{"id":3,"name":"Disposable","parent_id":0,"children":[{"id":21,"name":"Disposable","parent_id":3}]},{"id":4,"name":"SOE","parent_id":0,"children":[{"id":20,"name":"Cleaning Materials","parent_id":4},{"id":22,"name":"Chinaware","parent_id":4}]}]

function getNames(data) {
    var result = [];
    function loop(data, c) {
        data.forEach(function (e) {
            var name = !c.length ? e.name : c + '->' + e.name;
            if (e.children) { loop(e.children, name); }
            else {
                result.push({ name: name });
            }
        });
    }
    loop(data, '');
    return result;
}

console.log(getNames(arr))
```